# Javascript bitwise mask

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

Does anyone ever attempted to get a binary 'components' of a number?

What I'm trying to do is:

I have number: 5, so it is 0101 in binary. I'm trying find a sum of what numbers could give us 5. Obviously I know it is 1 and 4 ( 0001 and 0100 ) but I can't figure out way of getting that via code.

MDN has nice article on Bitwise Operators but still no joy.

Comment: so.... what is the algorithm you are aiming at? 1+4 is only one possibility. You also have 2+3

Comment: @VladimirM They want individual bits (1 = 0001, 4 = 0100) i.e. powers of two. 3 has more than one bit.

Comment: Just get the positions of the ones in the string representation, starting to count at 0 & _from the right_ -  2 to the power of position are the values you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var number = 5, 
    result = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= number; i = i << 1) {
  if(i & number) {
    result.push(i & number);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

The loop increments `i` in powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8...) using a bitwise shift (`i << 1` multiplies the number by two, you could also do `i *= 2`) and checks with bitwise AND (`&`) if the original number has that bit set. If so, it adds it as a number to the result array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Number.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) with a radix parameter.

```
var number = 5;
number.toString(2); // -> "101"
```

You can split that string and map using `Number` if you need the numbers themselves.

```
number.toString(2).split("").map(Number); // -> [1, 0, 1]
```

Just be sure to wrap the number in brackets if you don't want to store it as a variable first.

```
5.toString(2).split("").map(Number); // -> SyntaxError
(5).toString(2).split("").map(Number); // -> [1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generator-based solution that will yield a series of ones or zeroes:

```
const bits = *(n) => { do yield n & 1; while (n >>= 1); };

> console.log(Array.from(bits(5));
< [1, 0, 1]
```

You could then multiply the results by the corresponding powers of two, and or filter out zeroes, if you are so inclined.